# Equivalent definitions of $X$ being a generator for the category $R\text{-}\mathbf{mod}$

Tags: category-theory, modules

I'm in trouble with the definition of generator of $R\text{-}\mathbf{mod}$ category of left $R\text{-}\mathbf{mod}$. I've found a lot of equivalent definitions. I'm using the one of Jacobson's *Basic Algebra*, so $X$ is a generator if every module $M$ is sum of submodules all of which are homomorphic images of $X$.

Does it mean that these submodules are images of $X$ via homomorphisms?

Then I've proved that the following are equivalent:

1) $X$ is a generator;

2) the functor $\operatorname{hom}(X, -)$ is faithful;

3) $T(X)=R$ where $T(X) = \sum_{h \in \operatorname{hom}(X,R)} h(X)$;

4) $R$ is a homomorphic image of $X^n$ for some $n$.

Now I need to use the fact that $X$ is a generator if and only if every left $R$-module $M$ is an epimorphic image of some direct sum $\bigoplus_i X$.
Is this fact only a different way to write the definition I've used? I don't know what an epimorphic image is and I'm confused about this sentence.

If anybody can help me this will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a unital ring, you know that every module $M$ can be described as a homomorphic image of some free module $F$; since
$$
F \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}R
$$
for some index set $I$, you are pretty much done. Explicitly, let $M$ be a left $R$-module and let $F$ be a free module chosen such that you can realize $M$ as the homomorphic image of some map $\phi:F \to M$, i.e., $\operatorname{Image}(\phi) \cong M$. Then since there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $R$ is the homomorphic image of $X^{n}$, you get that
$$
F \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} R \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} X^n \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}\left(\bigoplus_{k=1}^{n}X\right) \cong \bigoplus_{j \in J} X
$$
where $I$ is some index set and $J$ is the evident new index set given by reindexing the double direct sum. Call the isomorphism from $F$ to this direct sum above $\alpha$, i.e.,
$$
\alpha:\bigoplus_{j \in J} X \to F.
$$
Then pre-composing $\phi$ with $\alpha$ gives a surjection
$$
(\phi\circ \alpha):\bigoplus_{j \in J} X \to M
$$
where
$$
\operatorname{Image}(\phi \circ \alpha) = \operatorname{Image}(\phi) = M
$$
because $\alpha$ is an isomorphism and $\phi$ is a surjection.

Comment: Your answer is very clear, thanks! So epimorphic image only means that there is a surjection (an epimorphism) such that $M$ is image via this epimorphism?

Comment: sorry but I still have some questions if you can answer.

Is being a generator equivalent to say that there is a split epimorphism $G^n \to R \to 0$? 

and from this how can I see that $G$ is a generator if and only if $G^n$ is the direct sum of $R$ and $R'$ for some module $R'$? Thanks again

Comment: @robbis Well a morphism in the category of left $R$-modules is epic if and only if it is surjective, so in this case it means that $M$ is the image of an epimorphism out of some domain you've chosen prior. Be careful in general, as there are categories in which epimorphisms are not surjective on underlying sets, but in module categories you're okay. Also if you like my answer, please consider upvoting it and accepting it! I'll answer your second comment in a second from here.

Comment: @robbis As for the second question, if you have a split epimorphism, you only need to show that there is a map $s:R \to G^n$ such that, if you call the morphism $e:G^n \to R$, $e \circ s = \operatorname{id}_A$, although this should fall out from the freeness of $R$ as an $R$-modlue. If you do get this, you should try to write $G^n$ as a direct sum of the kernel of $e$ and the image of $e$ (so think a Rank-Nullity Theorem for modules).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really help me and make me understand! Sorry but I don't use this forum very much, how can I upvote and accept your answer?

Comment: I used the fact that $R$ is free so is projective and I can find that map $s$. Now I consider the exact sequence $0 \to ker(e) \to G^n \to R \to 0$ and I apply the splitting lemma (if I'm not wrong, this is related to Rank Nullity Theorem) and I can say that $G^n= R \bigoplus ker(e)$

Comment: @robbis To upvote my answer, please click on the upwards pointing triangle beside the answer, while to accept it just click on the checkmark below the score of the answer. Also your last insight is entirely correct! If you have the map $s$ and you've used the splitting lemma you are totally done!

Comment: Thanks, now it's all clear to me! I'll upvote and accept surely! Thanks :)

Comment: @robbis You're very welcome! I'm glad that I could help you with this problem! Thank you very much as well for upvoting and accepting my answer; I really appreciate it!